# Median Computation of Points according to given angle

Tags: math, geometry

i'm programming a tree to divide the 2d-space.
therefore i need to split the current set of points in two equal parts according to a given angle. so the black line from the image attached below goes through the calculated median.

As we can see in the image, the line (defined by the given angle and the computed median) is far away from dividing the set in two equal parts. the line should cut the x-axis more to the right as now only ~25 points are on the left of the line and ~55 points on the right.

i already know, i have to use the angles of the point for my median computation.

my first approach for calculating the median was rotating all points by the given angle  and then use their angles to the x-axis, but that's obviously not enough.

I'm not concretly stuck on the transformations i have to apply to the point in order to have a correct median computation, so any help/hint would be appreciated,

thanks a lot.

[image: Not working]

Comment: Why does rotating the points not work?

Answer (score 0):

[Normal form of line equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_(geometry)#Normal_form) is

```
x * Cos(Theta) + y * Sin(Theta) - p = 0
```

where

```
Theta = Pi/2 + Fi
```

and `Fi` is your given angle.
You have to find appropriate `p` value to divide point set to two equal parts.

Signed [distance from this line to point Q](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line) is

```
D = Q.X * Cos(Theta) + Q.Y * Sin(Theta) - p
```

Sort your point array by D[i] value and find median.
If point number is odd, get D[median] as p for line equation, otherwise you may choose any p value between D[leftmedian] and D[rightmedian]

Examples:
5 points, D = (-3, -1, 4, 5, 8) - get p = 4 (line passes through one point)
6 points, D = (-3, -1, 2, 5, 7, 9) - get any p in range ]2..5[ (not including these values)

**Edit**: two examples for odd and even point numbers:

[image]
[image]

code (Delphi):

```
var
  Pt: TArray<TPoint>;
  D: TArray<Double>;
  N, i: Integer;
  Fi, Theta, p: Double;
begin
  Randomize;
  N := 7 + Random(2); // number of points, 7 or 8
  Fi := Pi / 4;   //line slope angle
  Theta := Pi / 2 + Fi;
  SetLength(Pt, N);   //point cloud
  SetLength(D, N);    //distance params
  Canvas.FillRect(ClientRect);

  //generate random points and draw them
  for i := 0 to N - 1 do begin
    Pt[i] := Point(Random(400), Random(400));
    Canvas.Rectangle(Pt[i].X - 2, Pt[i].Y - 2, Pt[i].X + 3, Pt[i].Y + 3);
  end;

  //fill param array
  for i := 0 to N - 1 do
    D[i] := Pt[i].X * Cos(Theta) + Pt[i].Y * Sin(Theta);

  //sort distance parameters
  TArray.Sort<Double>(D);

  //get line parameter as median of array
  if Odd(N) then
    p := D[N div 2]
  else
    p := (D[N div 2 - 1] + D[N div 2]) / 2;

  //draw calculated line
  Canvas.MoveTo(0, Round(p / Sin(Theta)));
  Canvas.LineTo(500, Round((p - 500 * Cos(Theta)) / Sin(Theta)));
```

Comment: i still have the problem finding the proper `p` value